# Is there a way to customize highlight colors in Preview (Mountain Lion and later)?

Tags: macos, preview

Since Mountain Lion, the highlight tool in Preview allows one to select among a small number of colors. Is there a way to customize the colors (add to or change)?

Comment: The only solution mentioned in [Can Mountain Lion's Preview.app be configured to use Lion's highlighting colours?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60122/can-mountain-lions-preview-app-be-configured-to-use-lions-highlighting-colours?rq=1) is to copy an old version of Preview to 10.8.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! ML Preview introduced some nice changes though which would be a shame to lose...

Comment: Colors are back in Mavericks..?

Comment: @beroe not sure if I understand your comment, as far as I can see Mavericks has the same limitations as Mountain Lion

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you were seeing even fewer options than the [limited] color palette that is available. I searched in the Resources and didn't find any place where that is set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change highlight color in Mavericks preview?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/change-highlight-color-in-mavericks-preview)

Answer (score 2):

What they are talking about is having more color choices for highlighting text than are available by default. Both the Yosemite choices in your post and the Mavericks choices (see below) limit the user to 5 preset colors. There doesn't appear to be any way to use the OS-built-in Apple color picker to choose anything other than this very limited set. Very frustrating.

[image: Mavericks highlight color choices]

Answer (score 0):

When you click the colour drop down on the annotations toolbar, you should see an **Other** option, that will allow you to pick arbitrary colours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that only works in Lion, not in Mountain Lion...

Comment: Ah sorry. I don't have a 10.8 machine handy to double check that, so I just took a stab at it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you guys really talking about, but in 10.10.2 everything works  just through the right click:

[image: example]

Comment: OP is asking if they can pick a custom color instead of being limited to the five shown in your screenshot.