# How can I customize the highlight colors in Preview?

Tags: preview

Is it possible to change the default highlight colors used by macOS's Preview?

Only yellow here is usable, other colors are toooo deep/dark that I think they didn't highlight, but de-highlight what I think important...

[image: macOS Preview.app screenshot showing highlighted text]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change highlight color in Mavericks preview?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/change-highlight-color-in-mavericks-preview) or [Is there a way to customize highlight colors in Preview (Mountain Lion and later)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63707/is-there-a-way-to-customize-highlight-colors-in-preview-mountain-lion-and-later?rq=1)

Comment: @GrahamMiln: I'm using Big Sur... Not Mavericks, and the chosen answer said it's not possible to solve it...

Comment: Only yellow here is usable, other colors are toooo deep/dark that I think they didn't highlight, but de-highlight what I think important...

Comment: Unfortunately nothing appears to have functionally changed since Mavericks. Be sure to [give Apple feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/); only they can address this commonly asked question.